# How to vertically center a group of bottom-aligned images?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 squares, side-by-side of different heights. I want them to be bottom-aligned with each other, but I want the entire group center-aligned within a containing box.

Seems like putting them in a wrapper whose style is `vertical-align:middle` should do it. But nope, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/IjqMn5W8xZxdy0XTWrAw?p=preview

```css
#red {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
#green {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
#blue {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
#wrapper {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id='wrapper'>
      <img id="red" src="">
      <img id="green" src="">
      <img id="blue" src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The group should be center aligned vertically, horizontally, or both?

Comment: vertical-align: middle; only works for inline and table elements.

Comment: can you show me any sample output of what you really need,i mean any image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container {
  display: table;
}
#wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/oYXOwg

You should use a table layout if not eager to use flexbox.

Comment: And to keep the container from streching:   table-layout: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display: flex;`.
The `#container` should have an `align-items: center;` property, and the `#wrapper` need an `align-items: flex-end;`

---

You can change `align-items` for this following options:

> - **flex-start:** cross-start margin edge of the items is placed on the cross-start line
> - **flex-end:** cross-end margin edge of the items is placed on the cross-end line
> - **center:** items are centered in the cross-axis
> - **baseline:** items are aligned such as their baselines align
> - **stretch (default):** stretch to fill the container (still respect    min-width/max-width)

Here for more about **[Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

---

And back to your question. Look at this **example**:

```css
#red {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

#green {
    background-color:#00FF00;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}

#blue {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height:100px;
    border: thin solid black;
}

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

body {
    font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <img id="red" src="">
            <img id="green" src="">
            <img id="blue" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/vsfh1j31/)